# Google Gmail Restrict delivery by API

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

My organization wants an application that configures users by organization units and restricts the delivery of emails to users. 
This could be easily done with the domain administration console: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en but I need something programatic.

I have searched in the Google Admin SDK  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk but I can't find the functionality.  Any help?

Regards.

Comment: There is no direct method to restrict email deliveries to users. But you can create an organizational unit, include users you want to send email then while sending restricting email just send to this group. I think admin console is the easiest option.

Comment: I agree that admin cnosole is the easiest option, but what I need is automates this process with an active directory synchronization. Reards anyway